# PHP file uploads: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

When i try to upload any file (via form submit), i get the following error:
"The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large".
I even get this error when uploading a 50kb jpg file

Ive tested my php web application on 8 servers and it works on all but one. Leading me to suspect that it isnt a code issue but an IIS setting. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx

Basically the fix is simply to up the size of the UploadReadAheadSize metabase property like this:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 204800
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually its IIS 7 so the command is slightly different to do this.
However, after more testing, it appears to be a firewall issue. ill get back to this thread when i get some more results